# Align text to edge of Label in ScrollView in kivy

Tags: android, python, scroll, label, kivy

I am trying to make Label scrollable horizontally and want `halign:"right` and `valign:middle` as per below code

```
ScrollView:

  Label:    
    id:maindisplay
    text:"0"
    font_size:"50sp"
    text_size: None ,self.height[1] #  Set the text wrap box height
    size_hint_x:None
    width: self.texture_size[0]

#Following part is not working
    halign: 'right'
    valign: 'middle'
```

[image]

Comment: How is it not working? What is the expected result?

Comment: Its not being align and valign.....its scrolling horizontally....but we want text at the right side and for that we used halign and valign which are not giving output

Comment: Make sure your label is indeed where you expect it with     `canvas.before:
      Color:
        rgba:1,0,0,1
      Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size`
And when I set `text:"1\n123"` It clearly is vertically in the center and right-aligned.

Comment: Maybe `text_size: self.width, self.height
    size_hint_x: 1` is what you want?

Comment: just check the edited question....and you will get that what i am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial point here is the width of the text. If it is set to `None`, it is unconstrained, and if the text is wider than the parent, it can be scrolled. However, if the text only requires a fraction of the width of the parent, the text will be centered inside the label (albeit multiple lines will still be right aligned). On the other hand, if `text_size` is statically set to a finite value, text that doesn't fit will wrap and there is never going to be scrolling. The hacky solution is to set `text_size: 8000, self.height` (something very wide, unlikely to ever occur). That allows scrolling, but is ugly (and one could accidentally scroll into the area where nothing is displayed).

Instead, we change the `text_width` dynamically. When `text` changes, we first remove the width constraint. We then let the label update its contents, and set `text_size` to be as wide as it has to be to fit the text, but at least as wide as the parent.

The other settings make sure the label itself is at least as wide as the parent (`width`) and that the `ScrollView` starts at its right edge (`scroll_x:1`)

Here is a complete example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty

kv = '''ScrollView:
  scroll_x: 1
  Label:
    canvas.before:
      Color:
        rgba:1,0,0,1
      Rectangle:
        pos: self.parent.pos
        size: self.size
    id:maindisplay
    text:"2"
    font_size:"50sp"
    text_size: None, self.height
    size_hint_x: None
    width:  max(self.texture_size[0], self.parent.width)
    halign: 'right'
    valign: 'middle'
    on_text: app.txt_cb(*args)
'''

class QApp(App):
    txt = StringProperty("1")
    num = NumericProperty(0)

    def add_string(self, dt=0):
        self.num += 1
        self.txt += "%i" % self.num
        self.root.ids.maindisplay.text = self.txt

    def txt_cb(self, obj, text):
        obj.text_size = (None, obj.height)
        obj.texture_update()
        obj.text_size = (max(obj._label.content_width, obj.parent.width), obj.height)

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt:self.txt_cb(self.root.ids.maindisplay, ""), 0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.add_string, .5)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QApp().run()
```

Comment: Trying this...just wait

Comment: it is not working.....i just want a scrollable label that has start text from right...not from left and it should be scroll in horizontal....

Comment: I got it to start the text from right but now it is not scrolling anymore

Comment: do you have any idea to get the text at right side and make it scroll also

Comment: nope it is not scrolling still...I coded as below  ScrollView:
  scroll_x: 1
  Label:
    canvas.before:
      Color:
        rgba:1,0,0,1
      Rectangle:
        pos: self.parent.pos
        size: self.size
    id:maindisplay
    text:"1899897723"
    font_size:"50sp"
    text_size: max(self._label.content_width, self.parent.width), self.height
    size_hint_x: None
    width:  max(self.texture_size[0], self.parent.width)
    halign: 'right'
    valign: 'middle'

Comment: Please answer for this and make it correct because i gave you 50 reputations today....so please help me to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102320/discussion-between-nisarg-and-zeemonkeez).

Comment: just hold...i am making it to run...i will tell you in 15 mins

Comment: Thanks for your effort and +1 for your answer

Comment: glad i could help. the actual problem wasn't quite obvious in the original question, so it took a bit to see what was going on...